# How can i attach the image to email in strapi using sendgrid?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, strapi

Trying to attach the image from response in strapi content-type using lifecycle hook like in this instruction https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/plugins/email, can't find no info for how to attach files with this method, this code below sends email, but image cant be sent and displays as an alt text of it

```
export default {
  async afterCreate(event) {
    const { result } = event

    try {
      await strapi.plugins["email"].services.email.send({
        to: `myemail@mail.com`,
        from: "noreply@mail.com", // e.g. single sender verification in SendGrid
        subject: `${result.messageSubject}`,
        text: `${result.message}

credits:

Name: ${result.name}
Mobile: ${result.phone}
E-mail: ${result.email}`,
        html: `<img alt="image in email" src="http://localhost:1337${result.attachment.formats.medium.url}" />`,
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the attachment property to the object. For the `content`, use `fs.readFileSync` to set the content. Specify the file `type` as `image/png`, and set the `disposition` to `attachment`
try this

```
export default {
async afterCreate(event) {

    /*---your code--- */

    try {
        const attachmentContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
        await strapi.plugins["email"].services.email.send({

            /*---your code--- */

            attachments: [
                {
                    content: attachmentContent,
                    filename: "attachment.png",
                    type: "image/png",
                    disposition: "attachment",
                },
            ]
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).